# What is a standard kit lens?

Tags: lens, terminology, kit-lens

I know what a kit lens is, but I am wondering what a **standard kit** lens is. There is a post for what a kit lens is, but I couldn't find a post on standard kit lenses. Standard or normal, in general, is the lens which sees quite like the human eye, in terms of field of view. This depends on the size of the image sensor. For example for a 24mm x 36mm sensor (full frame) the normal (standard) lens is 50mm.

So what is a *standard kit* lens? For example, why the **18-55mm** is a **standard kit** lens?

Comment: In terms of lenses the words *standard* and *normal* are not interchangeable. *Normal* refers to the focal length that, based on the sensor size, approximates the perspective (but no the field of view) of the human eye. *Standard* usually refers to the lens considered the base model.

Comment: @MichaelClark: Standard and normal are terms used interchangeably when we refer to lenses that ''see'' almost like a human eye. Pleace check out here:  photographymad.com/pages/view/standard-lenses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify, while there is a standard range of focal ranges (in between wide and telephoto) that isn't generally what the standard in standard kit lens refers to (though they are generally in the standard range.

Rather, when some cameras come with multiple possible kits, the standard kit lens is the cheaper one.  This is similar to how some features come "standard" on a car.  They are just the default option if you don't go for a body only or a more advanced kit.

Answer (score 2):

A standard kit lens is just a kit lens. However, for some models there can be different kits available. The standard kit lens will be a 18-55mm but additionally a 18-105mm kit also exists.

Answer (score 1):

The standard kit lens is just another word for the kit lens.

Certain cameras may come in a kit with a lens and sometimes there are more than one kit available with different lenses but if they are manufacturer bundles, then the lenses are known as standard kit lenses.

Comment: So a standard kit lens means the same as a kit lens. Right?

Comment: Well it depends on the kit. A lot of entry level cameras are sold in a kit that the manufacturer put together, using one of their 'standard kit lenses'. There aren't many standard kit lenses as they are used across various camera models. It is also possible to have a non standard kit lens, possibly as part of a retailer bundle.

Comment: Thank you! I wanted to know what standard in the case of standard kit lens means! ;)

Comment: *Standard* = base model.

Comment: This helps a lot, Michael! :)

Answer (score 1):

A standard kit is what typically is sold along with a body in kit offerings.

The EF 50mm 1.8 (the old one) used to be a standard kit lens too - ages ago.